# twitter bootsrap classes not imported in wicked_pdf

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4.1, wicked-pdf

I have install gem wicked_pdf for my app. For pdf generation in layout 
file "pdf.html.erb" include all css files

```
<%= Rails.application.assets.find_asset('user.css.scss').to_s.html_safe %>
<%= Rails.application.assets.find_asset('bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less').to_s.html_safe %>
<%= Rails.application.assets.find_asset('application.css').to_s.html_safe %>
```

It include a user.css.scss classes but not "twitter-bootstrap".

Answer (score 0):

```
 <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "application",media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

Hope this will work